# Separation in $l^1$ (Kreps-YanTheorem)

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-analysis, hyperplane-arrangements, separation-axioms

I have a question about the hypotheses of the Kreps-Yan Separation Theorem. I use the notation $l^p_+$ for the subspace of vectors all of whose coordinates are non-negative and define $l^p_- = -l^p_+$.

I am really interested in the $l^1$ case, but I present the $l^p$ version below.

I reproduce a version (where I hopefully correctly simplified the conclusion)  here:

**Theorem** (Kreps-Yan): Fix conjugate $p, q \in [1, \infty]$ and suppose that $C \subseteq  l^p$ is a convex cone with $C \supseteq l^p_-$ and $C \cap l^p_+= \{0\}$. If $C$ is closed in $σ(l^p, l^q)$ (meaning that it is weak* closed if $p = \infty$), then there exists a non-zero non-negative vector $q$ such that $q \cdot y \leq 0$ for all $y \in C$.

**Question**: Why is the presumption that $C \supseteq  l^p_-$  needed? If $C$ is a convex cone, wouldn't $C+l^p_-$ be another convex cone which also only intersects trivially with $l_+^p$?

After all, if there is an intersection point, then there is $c\in C, -v \in l_-^p, w\in l_+^p$ such that $c-v=w$, whereupon $c=v+w\in l_+^p$, and thus $c=0$. But, then $l_+^p \cap l_-^p = \{0\}$, so the condition is satisfied with the new $C$.

**Follow-up Question**: Is the issue that while $C$ is closed and $-l^p_+$ is closed, their sum $C+(-l^p_+)$ could be not closed? And if that's the case, then why not also take the closure of this cone. I would think that $cl(C+(-l^p_+))$ would still only intersect trivially with $l_+^p$.

**Final Follow-up**: Is it the case that things are well behaved for $l^p$, and so that $C \supseteq l^p_-$ is unnecessary for $l^1$ spaces, but it is important for more general spaces to which the theorem applies?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is the closure.

If we let $v_n=e_1-e_n/n+e_{n+1}$ and define $C$ to be the closed convex cone generated by $v_n$, then $C$ only intersects $L^1_+$ trivially.

Moreover, $\{v_n\}$ is not a convergent sequence in $l^1$, but if we let $w_n=-e_{n+1}$, then $v_n+w_n$ is convergent and converges to a member of $L^1_+$.